# Duplicate webform data to second database?

Tags: forms, database, webforms

I want to duplicate the results from the [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module to a second database.

Is there a convenient way to do that, or will I need to manually write all the queries to store and retrieve data?

Comment: Thanks Letharion for re-framming the question, i exaclty wanted to to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't try to tackle this at the Drupal level to be honest, it'll be a lot more trouble than it's worth.

If it was me I'd just add a trigger on the webform table that runs a stored procedure to copy the data into the second database.

There might be something you can do with [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html), but I'm not sure if it's granular enough to go down to the table level.